# UNIX timestamp conversion yields month as 0

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert a UNIX timestamp to a JavaScript date object. It works perfectly fine for all other inputs except the following,

```
dt = new Date(1421020800 * 1000);
dt.getMonth();    // yields '0'
```

For some mysterious reason, the ouput value is `0` for month, whereas the expected value as per [this link](http://www.convert-unix-time.com/?t=1421020800) should be `1`.

Does the month in Javascript date object starts with `0`?

Comment: Yes, January is month `0` in JavaScript.

Comment: Yep. [Not all that mysterious](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth#Returns)

Comment: @Pointy - Thanks! The same logic isn't applicable for `getDate()` though. It returns values from 1 to 31.

Comment: @PankajParashar yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal - you can read in [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp) (or anywhere else)

> The getMonth() method returns the month (from 0 to 11) for the
>   specified date, according to local time.
>
> Note: January is 0, February is 1, and so on.